# Click events are overlaying itself jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have problem with jQuery click events.

I think solution is easy, but it's hard to find and right formulate in english.

So this HTML code:

```
...
  <div id="element">
       <div id="button">
       </div>
  </div>
...
```

CSS code:

```
#element{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#button{ 
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#element',  function(){
      alert('element');
 });

 $('body').on('click', '#button',  function(){
      alert('button');
 });
```

And Execution:

if i click on #button it shows to me two alerts ('element') and ('button'), but if i click on #button i don't want click action from #element.

Thanks for any response

Comment: keep the button outside of element.

Comment: [__event.stopPropagation()__](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('body').on('click', '#button',  function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();    
  alert('button');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GFs4h/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use an if statement on click to show the button alert if it is the button that is clicked, else show other alert.

Answer (score 1):

`#button` is child of `#element`

```
 <div id="element">
    <div id="button"></div>
 </div>
```

Try doing this way

```
 <div id="element">Element</div>
 <div id="button">Button</div>

$('body').on('click', '#element',  function(){
      alert('element');
 });

 $('body').on('click', '#button',  function(){
      alert('button');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('body').on('click', '#button',  function(){
      alert('button');
      return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop propagation of children's events in parents

```
  $('body').on('click', '#element',  function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     alert('element');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '#button',  function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('button');
  });
```